# Swift EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (EXC_i386_INVOP) with Label

Tags: swift, xcode, compiler-errors, virtual-machine, hackintosh

I'm new to Swift so if this is a basic question don't burn me at the stake.
Before I start, I'd like to say I am running a virtual machine (hackintosh) on windows 10, using Mac OS X Sierra.

The project is a page-based application on Xcode 8.
Even without adding code at all, just label text w/o actions or outlets, and trying to run the code, gives me an error.

The code w/ the error:

```
import UIKit

class DataViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var dataLabel: UILabel!
    var dataObject: String = ""

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.dataLabel!.text = dataObject; // error here
    }
}
```

[image]

Been stuck on this and can't find much.

Comment: This has been asked and answered a million times but oddly I can't find a good duplicate. You never connected your `dataLabel` outlet so it's `nil`. And you are force unwrapping the `nil` pointer. That's bad.

Comment: @rmaddy please post an answer on how to fix so i can mark as answer